# Default sort attribute for Doctrine Model

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I was wondering if there is a way to declare the default order for my doctrine models.

e.g.

I have a `work` model and it has `photos`. When I load a work, all photos associated to it get loaded into `$work->photos`. When I display them, they are ordered by their IDs.

It would be very convenient to declare a default order on another field or perhaps override the fetch behaviour altoghether.

I'd rather not to convert the photos to an array and use usort. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify it in the YAML as follows:

If it's a sorting order for a field in the table itself add:

```
options:
  orderBy: fieldname
```

where `options:` is at the same depth as you'd have a `columns:` or `relations:` entry.  NB: The capitalisation of `orderBy:` is vital; get it wrong and you'll get no error but also no sorting.

If it's a sorting order for a relationship then, within the relationship you can skip the `options:` part and just put in:

```
orderBy: fieldname
```

Comment: Or by @OrderBy annotation: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby

Comment: Which yml file are you doing this in?

Comment: It depends. In doctrine1, the answer is valid (and it is about schema YAML file), but in doctrine2 it is just impossible to do. As a workaround, see @Alex's comment.

Comment: @OrderBy annotation is only applicable to relationships. It doesn't work on top-level entities. "You may only use this annotation on these code elements: PROPERTY" Also, this answer doesn't provide any way to define order direction.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I got around this thanks to this post: http://www.littlehart.net/atthekeyboard/2010/02/04/sorting-relationship-results-in-doctrine-1-2-2/

In my case, the BaseWork.php file had this modifications:

```
public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasMany('Photo as photos', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'orderBy' => 'display_order',
             'foreign' => 'work_id'));
```

Anyhow, it would be better to specify this in schema.yml, which I couldn't make work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the first thing about doctrine, but it looks like you can specify an order by clause when you call create().

http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/dql-doctrine-query-language:order-by-clause