# Default sort for doctrine model with annotations

Tags: annotations, doctrine-orm

In question at [Default sort attribute for Doctrine Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810868/default-sort-attribute-for-doctrine-model) a `.yml` is suggested to define a default sorting for a collection-valued association.

I would like to have my models fetched by a default sorting, like following:

```
Foo:
    columns:
    ...
    options:
        orderBy: bar DESC
```

What is the annotation equivalent of this YAML-based setup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT:** This is not possible with defaults. Entities fetched from repositories are fetched by the provided sorting criteria:

```
$entities = $entityRepository->findBy(array(), array('field' => 'ASC'));
```

This, [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) and the [Criteria API](https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3368674) are the current ways of fetching entities with a given sorting criteria.

What the question at " [Default sort attribute for Doctrine Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810868/default-sort-attribute-for-doctrine-model) " is about is the sorting of collection-valued associations, which has nothing to do with direct fetching of entities from repositories.

For those associations, the annotation-equivalent of " [Default sort attribute for Doctrine Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810868/default-sort-attribute-for-doctrine-model) " is  following (original answer):

As of the [official annotations documentation for Doctrine 2 ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#orderby), the annotation for default sorting conditions of collection-valued associations [`@OrderBy({"field" = "ASC", "otherField" = "DESC"})`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/OrderBy.php).

Here's how you would use it:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Users")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"username" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $users;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my question explicitly says: "Not just a relationship association, but the whole model". The link I mentioned is also pretty clear.

Comment: @bobdope that's not supported by the ORM. If you want to fetch with a particular sorting, use `$repository->findBy(array(), array('username' => 'ASC'))`. Annotations and mappings for sorting only work on associations. You asked for the equivalent of the linked question: this answer is that equivalent.

Comment: I researched further and found that I misunderstood the question I linked to. You're 100% right, sorry about that. I validated your answer.